# Is there a way to cast a b2Body to an Objective-C object

Tags: objective-c, box2d

I need to iterate through certain bodies. For that I want to add those bodies to an NSMurableArray. But as NSMutableArray accepts objective-c objects only, I need a way to cast b2Body to id. Trying `[bodiesArray addObject:(id)body];` does not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  [NSValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s  `valueWithPointer`

```
NSValue *bodyValue = [NSValue valueWithPointer:body];
[bodiesArray addObject:bodyValue];
```

and get your b2Body object back

```
b2Body *body = (b2Body*) [[bodiesArray objectAtIndex:0] pointerValue];
```